# See command-specific help message in sqlite shell

Tags: sqlite

> .help

works in an sqlite3 shell but how do I see the help message for each command such as FOR or WHERE?

Comment: Tried https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html ?

Comment: Yes, I looked up there but couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

`.help` provides help for SQLite's [dot-commands](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#special_commands_to_sqlite3_dot_commands_) and not for SQL clauses, operators and expressions which you can find in the online [documentation](https://sqlite.org/index.html).

So for example if you want help about the dot-command `trace` you can execute:

```
.help trace
```

Comment: Hi @forpas, you are right. I guess my problem is to navigate through that online documentation. For example, I am looking for help about `FOR` clause. Could you refer me to the exact html where I can find that?

Comment: @tash to which FOR clause? I don't know of a clause named FOR in SQLite. If you are referring to a clause similar to a looping FOR in other programming languages SQLite does not support that.

Comment: @tash if you are referring to `FOR each row` in triggers: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Comment: @tash have a look at https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-trigger/ ? Explains in text (not with example) how the FOR EACH ROW trigger works

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW` is optional and it is not even needed because this is the only type of trigger that SQLite supports: https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#description

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I understand now.